# Standard error for a difference-in-difference estimate

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, difference-in-difference

I am trying to calculate a difference-in-difference estimate. I have a binary outcome variable, and have estimated risk differences for my intervention and control groups.

If we take an example where:

- The intervention group has a risk difference of 0.03724 (i.e. 3.7% increase in the risk of the outcome) with a standard error of 0.01360
- The control group has a risk difference of 0.00410 with a standard error of 0.00316

Then we can calculate the difference-in-difference is 0.03724 - 0.00410 = +0.03314. What is the standard error of this estimate?

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402021/standard-error-confidence-intervals-for-a-difference-in-differences-analysis